# Заменить последний элемент массива в цикле foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть такой код

```
 <? foreach ($query as $data): ?>
    <div class="post"><?=$data[title] ?></div>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Можно ли при выводе последнего элемента массива добавить контейнеру div класс post-last?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такие вещи надо делать средствами CSS.

вместо `post-last` надо определить класс `.post:last-child` и никаких изменений в РНР код вносить не нужно

Answer (score 1):

```
<? $query_last = array_pop($query); ?>
<? foreach ($query as $data): ?>
    <div class="post"><?=$data[title] ?></div>
<? endforeach ?>
<div class="post post-last"><?=$query_last[title] ?></div>
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку `Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in`

Comment: Это очень плохой вариант, поскльку в нем приходится дублировать код.

Answer (score 0):

Можно выделить последний элемент и сравнить значения с ним.

Менее эффективный метод будет выглядеть так:

```
<?foreach($query as $data){?>
    <div class="post <?= ($data === end($query)) ? "post-last" : "" ?>"><?=$data['title'] ?></div>
<?}?>
```

Но лучше все-таки использовать получение элемента в начале, чем каждый раз это делать в цикле:

```
<?
    $end === end($query);
    foreach($query as $data){
?>
    <div class="post <?= ($data === $end) ? "post-last" : "" ?>"><?=$data['title'] ?></div>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Неплохо но оформите код как следует пожалуйста. Как то был у меня баг связаный с end() и next() по этому не использовал его больше.

Comment: @Naumov, не вижу никаких проблем в оформлении кода.

Comment: Совсем забыл сказать, что мне известно количество элементов и оно статично (пусть будет 3). Можно ли упростить код, зная это?

Comment: @AlexKrass как минимум убрать short tags, достаточно ординарных кавычек ` 'post-last' ` зачем сдесь двойные. сокращёный синтаксис `if, добавить переносы. Для человека то что вы написали сложно понять. Заменить теги echo на <?php echo $test ?>.

Comment: @Naumov, все, что Вы написали, являются вашими личными предпочтениями. А следовательно глупо просить кого-то следовать вашим личным необоснованным прихотям по стилю кодирования. Не вижу проблем с short-tags + после 5.4 они не вызывают больше вообще никаких проблем, в т.ч. синтаксис `<?= =>` после упразднения в php.ini опции short_open_tag. Никаких уточнений по версиям в вопросе нет. Одинарные или двойные кавычки - никакой разницы. Укороченный синтаксис if прост и читабельнее в данном случае, его не за раскрывать в полноценный if. Нормальный IDE подсветит код, поэтому переносы являются лишними.

Comment: @Naumov, глупо это говорить человеку которого Вы не знаете, особенно учитывая где я сейчас работаю и где я работал. Читайте изменения на офф. сайте: [PHP 5.4.0 offers a wide range of new features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). По умолчанию ее уже везде включают, если у Вас хостинг нормальный.

Comment: @AlexKrass либо в яндексе либо в microsoft там такие всегда нужны

Comment: Вы оба неправы. @Naumov неправ в  мелочности большей части своих претензий, но прав в том, что у него "как-то был баг", который, собственно, и является той причиной, по которой этот код использовать нельзя. Проверять надо обязательно ключ последнего элемента, а не значение.  И да, short_open_tag не следует путать с echo shorthand

Comment: @Ипатьев мои притензии не мелочны так при работе в команде, такой код убивает всё на прочь. Программист должен видеть что происходит. И не говорить что у меня работает а у вас нет но я сделал у меня работает. Пример из жизни, новый программист устанавливал 4 часа приложение так как до него понаписали short tegs поиспользовали всего всего, ошибок нет так как в принципе норм php отрабатывает а всё равно не работает... Или как пример, строка которая не умещаеться в ширину дисплэя, if(true) {999 строк} и т.д. и т.п. это всё жизнено.

Comment: @Naumov я вам настоятельно рекомендую унять преподавательский зуд, избавиться от желания всех учить, а вместо него приобрести реальные знания. Для начала попробуйте научиться писать комментарии строго по теме, а также проверять свои утверждения перед тем, как с таким пафосом садиться в лужу.

Comment: Да не, при чем здесь end внутри цикла? Значения в массиве не обязаны быть уникальными, то есть, этот код оформит как последний любой элемент, который равен последнему. А вот ключи в отличие отзначений всегда уникальны, поэтому по ключу такую проверку проводить можно.

Comment: @Naumov ха-ха, да вы батенька шутник у нас. Я повторю, вы обо мне ничего не знаете, но судите. Я могу так же авторитетно сказать, что Вы у нас "талантливый" программист, который живет в коробке и мечтает о заработках. Это будет такой же правдой. Впрочем, разговаривать с Вами не о чем, считайте себя профессионалом дальше.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $i=1; $counter = count($data)>
<?php foreach($query as $data): ?>
    <div class="post <?php if($i == $counter) echo 'post_last'?>" ><?php echo $data['title'] ?></div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

и мой вам совет не используйте short tag. Ибо даже на php.net написано што их использование не желательно.
   Если массив не ассоциативный то лучше использовать for для таких целей

```
 <?php $counter = count($data)>
 <?php for($i=0;$i<$counter;$i++): ?>
    <div class="post <?php if($i == $counter-1) echo 'post_last'?>" ><?php echo $query[$i]['title'] ?></div>
 <?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Совсем забыл сказать, что мне известно количество элементов и оно статично (пусть будет 3). Можно ли упростить код, зная это?

Comment: @n000000b да и так в принципе всё просто. массив какого вида?