# Условие последнего элемента в foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Существует ли условие последнего элемента без использования функции count().
Как можно оптимизировать, сократить данный код?

```
$i=0;
$count = count($breadcrumbs);
foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) {
    $i++;
    if ($i != $count) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $breadcrumb['href'] . '">' . $breadcrumb['text'] . '</a></li>';
    }else {
        echo '<li><span>'.$breadcrumb['text'].'</span></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Эдуард разве из кода не видно, что ему надо получить?

Comment: Нужно изменить форму вывода ЕСЛИ последний элемент

Comment: не оптимизируете вы особо этот код. разве что сделаете форму `$k => $breadcrumb`. и будете проверять `$k == count($)`, когда ключи по порядку

Comment: `++$i == $count` можете напиать, строку сэкономите :)

Comment: еще можно сделать `array_pop` вывести цикл ссылок, а потом отдельно элемент последний.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485964/186083

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, такое имели в виду?

```
$count = count($breadcrumbs);
foreach ($breadcrumbs as $key => $breadcrumb) {
    if ($key != $count) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $breadcrumb['href'] . '">' . $breadcrumb['text'] . '</a></li>';
    }else {
        echo '<li><span>'.$breadcrumb['text'].'</span></li>';
    }
}
```

Или ещё вариант

```
$end = array_pop($breadcrumbs);
foreach($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) {
   echo '<li><a href="' . $breadcrumb['href'] . '">' . $breadcrumb['text'] . '</a></li>';
}

echo '<li><span>'.$end['text'].'</span></li>';
```

Comment: особенный фэйл будет, если ключи например id элементов, или вообще ассоциативные

Comment: @teran добавил еще вариант, которому плевать на это

Comment: бгг :) одновременно коммент написал :)

Comment: @СашаБоричевский Спасибо. Мне второй вариант понравился. Отличная идея!

Comment: @Дмитрий рад помочь)